# CKEditor 4 - How to deactivate spellcheck in Source view

Tags: spell-checking, ckeditor4.x

In wysiwyg mode using CKEditor 4, spellcheck is not enabled. Words can be misspelt & ignored by the Editor as below. This is desired behaviour in our case.[screenshot of misspelt word being ignored which is the desired behaviour in our scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QukSV.png)

In Source view however, the same word is picked up as misspelt with a red dotted underline which is not desired behaviour in our case. [screenshot of same misspelt word being picked up & marked with red dotted line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Prt4.png)

How do we prevent spellcheck running (assuming this is what's triggering the red dotted underline) when viewing content in Source view & thereby also stop html code being highlighted with dotted red underlines because the spellcheck simply doesn't recognise them?

Comment: Maybe your browser's native spellchecker

Comment: Thanks.  I'm in Chrome and spell checker is off - I hadn't checked before.
When activated (as it now is) some of the text that was previously underlined in red dots, not all of it, is now underlined in green dots.  Deactivating Chrome's spelling web service reverts the green back to red where it has changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested the following official demo link:
https://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/spellchecker.html

1- Disable the spell checker via the **ABC** button in the toolbar

2- Disable the browser's native spellchecker

On Chrome: Settings > Advanced Settings > Languages > Spell Check
(turn off the active languages)

All errors both in WYSIWYG and Source windows should be gone.

**Other possible solutions**:

- CKEditor4 Configuration:

  https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-scayt_autoStartup

  https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-disableNativeSpellChecker
- Submit issues for WebSpellChecker on Github (https://github.com/WebSpellChecker/ckeditor-plugin-wsc), as it's the third party responsible for the spell checker:

  > The Standard and Full CKEditor packages include the integrated spell checking functionality. It is an out-of-the-box solution provided by
  >   third-party plugins, WebSpellChecker and SpellCheckAsYouType (SCAYT),
  >   that use the WebSpellChecker.net web service.
- If you do not want any spell checking, then disable these plugins. If the **ABC** button is no longer there, your problem should be solved.

  > When either of the
  >   plugins is enabled, the button is automatically added to the toolbar.
  >   Depending on which plugin you use, it may contain numerous SCAYT
  >   options and open the Spell Check dialog window.

Comment: **Thank you**  This resolved the issue in combination with ensuring the browser spell checker was deactivated. Much appreciated.